# Image is not getting uploaded

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to create a application called Smart Contact Image in which i need to upload files. I am saving that file in my project static folder in img folder in userinputimg folder I am taking the name of of the file and saving it in my db. But the program is unable to save the image in db as well as in the folder. It is aso not stroig the other data which is given. Please help me solve this.
My code->

```
@PostMapping("/process-contact")
    public String processContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact, @RequestParam("profileImage") MultipartFile imgFile,
            Principal principal) {
        try {

            String name = principal.getName();
            User user = repo.getUserByUsername(name);

            if (imgFile.isEmpty()) {

            } else {
                contact.setImageUrl(imgFile.getOriginalFilename());
                File file = new ClassPathResource("static/img/UserInputImg").getFile();

                Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + imgFile.getOriginalFilename()
                    + contact.getcId() + contact.getContactName() + "_img");
                Files.copy(imgFile.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                System.out.println("Img added");
        
                user.getContacts().add(contact);
                contact.setUser(user);

                this.repo.save(user);
                System.out.println("Added to db");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        return "user-add-contact";
    }
```

My File structure

[image: This is my file structure]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `src/main/resources` folder is meant to contain static read-only resources that will be packaged into your JAR at compile time (which at runtime can be accessed via e.g. `ClassPathResource`). When uploading files you should store them in the file system instead (via e.g. `FileSystemResource`).

Comment: Sorry. But FileSystemResources is not working

Comment: I was explaining some very basic concepts only – don't know what you tried actually. I'd recommend you to read some guides about this topic first (e.g. [Uploading Files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)).